# Deserialize multiple XML elements have same name

Tags: c#, xml

i have an XML form look like this:

```
<Myset>
   <element>1A</element>
   <element>2B</element>
   <element>3C</element>
   <element>AB</element>
   ..........
   <element>AA</element>
```

What should structure class, variables should i use to deserialize it. I want to read and update value of each element. I have try this, but it doesn't work:

```
public class Myset
{
  public List<string> element {get; set;}
  // or public string[] element { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How you deserialize? Didn;t you miss any attributes?

Answer (score 2):

[XmlElementAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) will allow you specify element name.

```
public class case_id_list
{
  [XmlElement("case_id")]
  public List<string> case_id {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: But in xml it is `case_id` not `case-id`

Comment: Sorry, that was typo on my part.

Comment: Specify an ElementName if you want the name of the generated XML element to ***differ from the member's identifier.***

Comment: i have try this, but maybe because my serialize function is not good (i am using a serialize-funcion in an external reference) so it doesn't work like what i' like. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @NguyenBaTu Show your code if you want feedback on that. We con't give feedback if there is no code.

Comment: @loopedcode I'm sorry that, i'm not allowed to public source code. I found that the function is using WriteObject(XmlWriter, Object)/ ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader) methods of class [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) to write/read object in XML file.I think i have to create a [DataContract] class.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this **[service](http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)**. It converts your xml structure to valid c# model structure. It's a very useful tool.

*In case you ever want to convert your JSON to C# this is another useful **[service](http://json2csharp.com)**.

Cheers!